# mostrar una imagen mientras exista la dirección url

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero mostrar una imagen mientras exista la dirección url, es por decir que no devuelve 404. Entonces intenté conectarme al menos una vez y hacer lo con una bucle `while` hasta que me devuelve otra cosa que 200.

```
import urllib.request
import http.client

i = 0
c = http.client.HTTPSConnection(port=int("//i.prcdn.co/img?file=f6412019030100000000001001&page=1&scale=88"))
while(c.getresponse().status == 200):
    urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://i.prcdn.co/img?file=f6412019030100000000001001&page={0}&scale=88".format(i), "page{0}.jpg".format(i))
    i+=1
```

Sin embargo obtengo:

```
(urlenv) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\projects\scrapping\UrlRetrieve>py ImageMagazineRetriever.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ImageMagazineRetriever.py", line 5, in <module>
    c = http.client.HTTPSConnection(port=int("//i.prcdn.co/img?file=f6412019030100000000001001&page=1&scale=88"))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '//i.prcdn.co/img?file=f6412019030100000000001001&page=1&scale=88'
```

Comment: Claro, en la línea que pone `c = http.client.HTTPSConnection(port=int("...")` lo que le estás pasando a `int` como parámetro (el `"..."'`) no es para nada un entero. Más bien parece una URL. No sé qué pretendías exactamente.

Answer (score 0):

A [`http.client.HTTPConnection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPConnection) hay que pasarle un cadena con el dominio del servidor y, opcionalmente, el puerto separado por los dos puntos `':'`.

Como le pasas la cadena `"https://i.prcdn.co/img?file=f6412019030100000000001001&page=1&scale=88"` considera como `host` a `"https"` y como *puerto* el resto de la cadena, o sea, `port=int("//i.prcdn.co/img?file=f6412019030100000000001001&page=1&scale=88")` que da error.

En realidad, ya que usas el protocolo `HTTPS`, deberías usar mejor [`HTTPSConnection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPSConnection).

Comment: Puesto al dia el codigo. Sin embargo obtengo un `ValueError` : `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '//i.prcdn.co/img?file=f6412019030100000000001001&page=1&scale=88'`

Comment: No has entendido mi respuesta. Echa un vistazo a la documentación de [HTTPConnection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPConnection).

Answer (score 0):

`http.client.HTTPSConnection` no funciona como esperas. No puedes pasarle una URL, sino sólo el nombre del host al que quieres conectar, para después usar su método `request` especificando el verbo http y la ruta a acceder dentro de ese site.

Es mucho más sencillo usar la biblioteca `requests`, que sí que hace lo que tú esperabas de `http.client`. Con esta librería el código queda así:

```
import requests
import time
url = "https://i.prcdn.co/img?file=f6412019030100000000001001&page={}&scale=88"

i = 1
r = requests.get(url.format(i))
while(r.status_code == 200):
    print(i, "OK")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    i += 1
    r = requests.get(url.format(i))
```

Observa que he metido un retardo de medio segundo entre peticiones, para ser "amable" con el sitio y que no te tome por un ataque DOS.